# iPhone 4S won't sync with iTunes

Tags: iphone, itunes, ios

My iPhone 4S doesn't show in the left column in iTunes. I'm running iTunes 10.6.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Are you plugged in via USB or syncing wirelessly?

Answer (score 1):

1 - Restart.

2 - Hard reset (home and power buttons).

3 - If you have it, the XCode device manager sometimes detects devices that iTunes does not.

One of those three should solve the problem entirely, and if not - jailbroken? also any error messages?

Comment: Thanks for the tips :) Tried 1 and 2 to no luck. The iPhone doesn't show up under Devices in XCode. The phone is not jailbroken, and I don't see any error messages.

Comment: I also tried this on another Mac, I won't show up in iTunes there either.

Comment: I've erased all media and settings, no success :(